# durable brokerless lightweight message queue

Tags: storage, messaging

I'm looking for durable(with dumping to FS) brokerless and lightweight queue or storage. In fact, I need solution for sequential writing messages to FS from one process, and for sequential reading from another process under Linux. Processes can be started or stopped during exchange. Also, messages must be recoverable after reboot. Good perfomance will be a plus.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.